# Not able to send the comment to db and getting "IntegrityError at /add-comment NOT NULL constraint failed: core_comment.post_id"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

**models.py**

This was the model I created :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    caption = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    no_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.user, self.name)
```

**views.py**

I am not able to create object at the backend. would be helpful if anyone knew how to call post and add it to the views.

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        user = request.user.username
        comment = request.POST['comment']

        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(name=user, body=comment)
        new_comment.save()

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

**index.html** : along with forms

```
 <!-- Comment section  -->

                        <form action="add-comment" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div>
                                <!-- Comment section typing box  -->
                                <div class="bg-gray-100 bg-gray-100 rounded-full rounded-md relative ">
                                    <!-- <a href="/add-comment?post_id={{post.id}}"> -->
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="post a comment"
                                        class="bg-transparent max-h-10 shadow-none" name="comment" id="comment">
                                    <div class="absolute bottom-0 flex h-full items-center right-0 right-3 text-xl space-x-2">
                                        <button class="button bg-blue-700" type="submit">submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

I am not able to bring the comment to the backend as I am new to django.[image]

comment section looks like this

[image: error picture]

**tracebackcall**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify for which post you add the comment, so:

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def add_comment(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user.username
        comment = request.POST['comment']
        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(
            name=request.user.username, body=comment, post_id=pk
        )
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

in the URLs, you thus will need to provide a primary key:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add-comment/<uuid:pk>/', add_comment, name='add-comment'),
    # …
]
```

and in the form you will need to pass the primary key of the post:

```
<form action="{% url 'add-comment' post.pk %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    …
</form>
```

where `post.pk` should be a template expression that resolves to the primary key of the post for which you want to add a comment.

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* store the username of the user, but work with a `ForeignKey` to the user object. If later the user changes their username, this will result in a lot of trouble. It also makes querying the database less effective, since Django can work with JOINs on `ForeignKey` fields.

Comment: how do I add the image of commentor along with the comment over here.
 @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.post** the ForeignKey, is empty. You need to add that inside of your add_comment & Comment.objects.create

There's a couple of way you can do this, but the easiest **IMO** would be to add a hidden field inside your `<form></form>` and when you hit submit it'll be submitted by default.

Something like:

##### html

```html
<form action="add-comment" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
    <!-- Comment section typing box  -->
    <div class="bg-gray-100 bg-gray-100 rounded-full rounded-md relative ">
    <!-- <a href="/add-comment?post_id={{post.id}}"> -->

  
    <!-- Hidden field here -->
    <input hidden type="text" id="post" name="post" value="{{post.id}}"/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="post a comment"
    class="bg-transparent max-h-10 shadow-none" name="comment" id="comment">

    <div class="absolute bottom-0 flex h-full items-center right-0 right-3 text-xl space-x-2">
      <button class="button bg-blue-700" type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

##### View

```py
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        user = request.user.username
        comment = request.POST['comment']
        post_id = request.POST['post']

        # way #1 (fetching object)
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(post=post_obj, name=user, body=comment)

        # way #2 (using _id)
        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(post_id=post_id, name=user, body=comment)

        new_comment.save()

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: how do I add the image of commentor along with the comment over here. @Nealium